# SimpleDb as database for rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, railstutorial.org, amazon-simpledb

I'm Following the wonderful Michael Hartl's tutorial which can be found here:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

I'm trying to modify my database backend from PostgreSQL to Amazon SimpleDB.. Any ideas on how to achieve this without breaking my existing app would be most helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a serious endeavor you are undertaking?

Comment: yes. I understand I'm moving from a relational database backend to a key, value storage system.. but I was hoping there was some support for RoR with Amazon SimpleDB.. I plan to write another application from scratch using Amazon SimpleDB once I have mastered how to use it with rails.

Comment: The change to key value store, as opposed to a relational store, requires a completely different way of thinking about your data access. It will, be necessity, break your existing app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Tutorial covers a lot of ActiveRecord specifica which you probably can't use on AWS, I can't see why you would want to port the Tutorial app to AWS. Here's an intro about creating Rails Applications with Simple DB:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8621639827664165